# breaking on unhandled exceptions in pydev/gae

Tags: pydev

i am using pydev to develop a google app engine application. i followed the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455552/break-on-exception-in-pydev) to configure pydev debugger to break on unhandled exception. i could get it to work on a sample pydev project, but when i try the same steps in my pydev gae project, it doesn't work and gives following error:

> pydev debugger: warning: psyco not
>   available for speedups (the debugger
>   will still work correctly, but a bit
>   slower) pydev debugger: starting
>   ...
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "c:\program
>   files\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py",
>   line 3858, in _HandleRequest
>       self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)   File
>   "c:\program
>   files\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py",
>   line 3792, in _Dispatch
>       base_env_dict=env_dict)   File "c:\program
>   files\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py",
>   line 580, in Dispatch
>       base_env_dict=base_env_dict)   File "c:\program
>   files\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py",
>   line 2918, in Dispatch
>       self._module_dict)   File "c:\program
>   files\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py",
>   line 2822, in ExecuteCGI
>       reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path,
>   hook)   File "c:\program
>   files\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py",
>   line 2702, in ExecuteOrImportScript
>       exec module_code in script_module.**dict**   File
>   "C:\Users\siddjain\workspace\rfad\src\main.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import pydevd ImportError: No module named pydevd

my debug configuration for gae project is like this:
[image]

the sample pydev project where it works is like this and am following same pattern in my gae project:

```
import pydevd

def f(x,y):
    z = y/x;
    return z;

def main():
    pydevd.set_pm_excepthook()
    print f(0,0)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

the run config for test project is like this:
[image]

the pydevd.py module is under C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.0.0.2011040403\pysrc. Although this path is not included in the pythonpath for test project, the breaking works in test. i also tried including this path in pythonpath of gae project to see if that fixes my problem, but it didn't

Answer (score 1):

Its still not fixed although following steps got rid of No module named pydevd error:
1. Create a symlink to C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.0.0.2011040403\pysrc:
src>mklink /d debugger C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.0.0.2011040403\pysrc
2. Put an empty __init__.py file in C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.0.0.2011040403\pysrc. i learnt this from some google link that i can't find now.
3. In source code:
import debugger.pydevd as pydevd

after these steps its able to import pydevd, but still doesn't break on uncaught exception.
The development server runs your application on your local computer for testing your application. The server simulates the App Engine datastore, services and **sandbox restrictions** (hence step 1). although i don't understand why we need to import pydevd since its pydevd who's running our application in the first place!
In the Run->Debug Configurations->Interpreter tab if I click on "see resulting command line..."
C:\Python25\python.exe -u
C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.0.0.2011040403\pysrc\pydevd.py
--vm_type python --client 127.0.0.1 --port 0 --file "c:\program
files\google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py"

The PYTHONPATH that will be used is:

C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.0.0.2011040403\PySrc\pydev_si...