# Break on unhandled exception in pycharm

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm

Does anyone know how to break on unhandled exceptions in pycharm? per [this link](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/PY-1498) it should be possible, although its not breaking for me (build 105.58). Is there some switch I have to turn on to enable this?

EDIT: I did what you suggested, but the debugger is not breaking on unhandled exceptions. Please see the screenshot below, and let me know if I need to do something else.
[image]

It seems this is the same issue as [breaking on unhandled exceptions in pydev/gae](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761928/breaking-on-unhandled-exceptions-in-pydev-gae). Pycharm uses pydevd for the debugger.

```
C:\Python25\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 1.2.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --client 127.0.0.1 --port 49371 --file C:/Users/morpheus/PycharmProjects/untitled1/main.py
pydev debugger: warning: psyco not available for speedups (the debugger will still work correctly, but a bit slower)
pydev debugger: starting
Connected to pydev debugger (build 105.58)
```

I can get it to break on a non-gae project, but it won't break on a gae project. How can this be fixed?

Comment: I found the answer here useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988590/stop-pycharm-if-error/66907734#66907734

Answer (score 41):

Please [check the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/creating-exception-breakpoints.html):

> To create an exception breakpoint
>
> 1. On the main menu, choose Run | View Breakpoints, or press
>      Ctrl+Shift+F8.
> 2. Select the Exception Breakpoints tab.
> 3. Click Add button.
> 4. In the Enter Exception Class dialog, specify the desired exception
>      class from the library, or from the
>      project, and click OK.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on what exactly an `Exception Class Dialog` means, and how this might actually work?  Is this simply the string that an exception throws?

Comment: @DerekAdair, it [opens a dialog](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/9751/20121102044459.png) where you can select the class name, it's just a string representing the name of the class.

Comment: At least in PyCharm 3.4, this does not work unless you're willing to suspend every time the exception is raised, whether it's caught or not.

Comment: How do you toggle that setting, @Peter?

Comment: Recent versions of PyCharm break on exceptions by default. The setting is now in a checkbox in a tree list in the Run/View Breakpoints.

Comment: Can anyone suggest why that option toggled itself in my project?

Answer (score 7):

Now on Pycharm 5(at least) you can make it break on unhandled exceptions by checking "all exception" and "on terminate".