# How to make pycharm break on My Exceptions

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [break on unhandled exception in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839286/break-on-unhandled-exception-in-pycharm)

I'm new in Python and I'm trying to debug my first python program using PyCharm 1.5. 
I want debugger to break when exception occurs in my code (and only in mine).

For now the situation is following: I use (Ctrl + Shift + F8 ) Dialog to configure debugger and If i set **Suspend All = true** and **All exceptions = true** then debugger breaks far too often, for example, it breaks somewhere inside PyCharm 1.5.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py which is annoying to skip every time. And if I set any other options then debugger does not break even when exception occurs in my code.

**PS:** By the way, if I just skip breaks in PyCharm 1.5.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py then execution continues without visible errors. So I do not understand why it breaks at all

Comment: If you don't get an answer here it might be worth raising an issue at [the Pycharm issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/PY).  This looks like it could be a bug.  Pycharm probably shouldn't be breaking on exceptions in its own code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, I'll post here if I find what's up

Comment: did it work when you add a debugger point on any location ?

Answer (score 3):

One way to tell apart your exceptions from exceptions coming from a library, is to have them derive from a custom class, e.g. if your module is called Foo, you could have

```
class FooException(Exception):
   pass
```

and have more specific exceptions derive from this:

```
class MyMathException(FooException):
   # etc.
```

Then, in PyCharm, instead of enabling `All Exceptions`, add `FooException` to the list of exceptions to break upon.

Comment: I agree with what you said, but usually it is not me who raises an exception

Comment: Oh. I'm confused now though, you said "when exception occurs in my code (and only in mine)."

Comment: Yes, for example, if I call missing method then exception happens in my code but it is not me who throws an exception