# Pycharm: Enter debugger when uncaught error raised

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm new to pycharm. How can i configure pycharm to enter debugger when any error raised?

I was using Ipython before. In Ipython Console if error raised you simply type `%debug` and will enter `ipdb`.

However in pycharm Ipython Console, after I entered `%debug` it displays this message: `ERROR: No traceback has been produced, nothing to debug.`

I've followed [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-exception-breakpoints.html) Official Doc and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839286/break-on-unhandled-exception-in-pycharm) question but none of them work.

By the way, what's the function of `debug` icon on pycharm console? Nothing happens even I activated it.

Sample code:

```
def debugg():
    a = 1
    a[3]
debugg()
```

Comment: Did you configured your debug settings before actually running debug on PyCharm?

Comment: @Samuel I'm not sure what is the "debug settings" in Pycharm. Would you please post me a link?

Comment: Please check that link - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Comment: @spacegoing, try to press `Ctrl + Shift + F8` and check the "Python Exception Breakpoint" checkbox.