# python Eclipse - how to break/pause on warning?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I found this which allows to break on exception.

[Break on exception in pydev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455552/break-on-exception-in-pydev/6655894#6655894)

However, what I'd like is to break on a warning. This is the warning I get and would like if this or another warning are reported to break at that point.

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars  yv = Nv(v, U*r)/Nv(v, U*r_)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike a exception, which is associated with several flow control mechanisms, a warning is simply text that is outputted to the console - more exactly, to the [`stderr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stderr#Standard_error_.28stderr.29):

A possible way to break on warnings would thus be intercepting calls to `stderr`:

```
class MyStderr(object):
    def __init__(self, original_stderr):
        self.original_stderr= original_stderr
    def my_break(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    def write(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.my_break()
        #...
    def writelines(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.my_break()
        #...
    #...
import sys
sys.stderr= MyStderr(sys.stderr)
```

This should launch the interactive `pdb` debugger.

Comment: sorry if this is somewhat obvious, but where would my code go?

Comment: @evan54 You can put this just on the beginning of your file